# Getting "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method X" in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

When I run this command from my view in `exceptions.html`

```
 <tr ng-repeat="scbEXCEPtions in vm.scbExpData">
     <td>
       <button class="btn btn-alert btn-xs" ng-click="vm.DelExceptionObjRef(scbEXCEPtions.REF_ID)">
          Remove
      </button>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

and in my controller file `exception.js`, this is the method I call

```
  vm.DelExceptionObjRef = function (refno) {
        vm.viewModelHelper.apiGet('api/scbexception/RevertExceptionById/' + refno, null,
        function (result) {
            vm.prepareData(result.data);
        },
        function (result) {
            toastr.error(result.data, 'Fintrak');
        }, null);
   }
```

which generates this URL when clicked on, even after setting a breakpoint  on the apicontroller file, I get this error:

```
http://localhost:6861/api/scbEXCEPtion/RevertExceptionById/10000011943
```

and I have a method in my Api Controller { `ScbExceptionApiController` } that receives the function and method here...

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("RevertExceptionById/{ID}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage RevertExceptionById(HttpRequestMessage request, int ID){
        return GetHttpResponse(request, () => {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            ScbException[] scbexception = _APPModuleService.RevertExceptionById(ID);
            response = request.CreateResponse<ScbException[]>(HttpStatusCode.OK, scbexception);
            return response;
        });
    }
```

but after execution I get this error, and I don't understand why

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage RevertExceptionById(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, Int32)' in 'Fintrak.Presentation.WebClient.API.ScbExceptionApiController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RevertExceptionById(HttpRequestMessage request, int ID)` is expecting `ID` as an `int`, which is a 32-bit integer.

The [max value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.8) of a 32-bit integer is `2147483647`. You're passing `10000011943` as the ID, which is exceeding this max value.

I suspect this is the reason the parameter binding for `ID` is failing with the given exception.

Possible solutions could be: use lower ids, or use `string` instead of `int` for the ID.